# Could not open library 'lib.dylib' on Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems, apple-m1

Have some issues with launching ruby tests on Mac(Monterey 12.2.1). I've launched `bundle install` - everything was finished successfully, after that I tried to do a command `bundle exec rake db:test:refresh`, and got the following error

```
LoadError: Couldn't load the GEOS CAPI library.
/Users/alexandra_shimanovich/.bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/ffi-geos-0.3.0/lib/ffi-geos.rb:1000:in `rescue in <module:FFIGeos>'
/Users/alexandra_shimanovich/.bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/ffi-geos-0.3.0/lib/ffi-geos.rb:982:in `<module:FFIGeos>'
/Users/alexandra_shimanovich/.bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/ffi-geos-0.3.0/lib/ffi-geos.rb:51:in `<module:Geos>'
/Users/alexandra_shimanovich/.bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/ffi-geos-0.3.0/lib/ffi-geos.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/alexandra_shimanovich/Documents/Curb/ride_manager/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/alexandra_shimanovich/Documents/Curb/ride_manager/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/Users/alexandra_shimanovich/Documents/Curb/ride_manager/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/alexandra_shimanovich/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/Users/alexandra_shimanovich/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
LoadError: Could not open library '/usr/lib/': dlopen(/usr/lib/, 0x0005): tried: '/usr/lib/' (not a file), '/usr/local/lib/' (not a file).
Could not open library 'lib.dylib': dlopen(lib.dylib, 0x0005): tried: 'lib.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/lib.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/lib.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/alexandra_shimanovich/Documents/Curb/ride_manager/lib.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/lib.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/lib.dylib' (no such file)
```

I looked inside ffi-geos.rb

```
def self.search_paths
      @search_paths ||= begin
        if ENV['GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH']
          [ ENV['GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH'] ]
        elsif FFI::Platform::IS_WINDOWS
          ENV['PATH'].split(File::PATH_SEPARATOR)
        else
          [ '/usr/local/{lib64,lib}', '/opt/local/{lib64,lib}', '/usr/{lib64,lib}' ]
          [ '/usr/local/{lib64,lib}', '/opt/local/{lib64,lib}', '/usr/{lib64,lib}', '/usr/lib/{x86_64,i386}-linux-gnu' ]
        end
      end
    end
```

I know that in my computer lib files are not in `/usr/local/..` but in `/opt/homebrew/lib`. But when I looked inside `/opt/homebrew/lib` I didn't find `lib.dylib`. There are only `libgeos.3.10.2.dylib libgeos.dylib libgeos_c.1.16.0.dylib libgeos_c.1.dylib libgeos_c.dylib`.

Please, help me find the right lib and somehow tell ffi-geos.rb to look in the right place, I would REALLY appreciate it! Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried setting GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH to `/opt/homebrew/lib`? That might just do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I looked inside /opt/homebrew/lib I didn't find lib.dylib

The code from `ffi-geos.rb` you posted is not looking for `lib.dylib` (or `lib64.dylib`), but it's adding `/usr/local/lib`, `/usr/local/lib64`, etc, to the search path to look for the specific GEOS dylibs. As your library files are in `/opt/homebrew/lib`, they won't be found by that automatic procedure.

The first conditional in the code shows you can set an environment variable to define the search path. So, set the library path with:

```
export GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/lib
```

Hope this works!